# Is the set of functions with 1 discontinuity equinumerous to the set of continuous functions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, continuity

Let $D(\mathbb{R})$ be defined as $\{f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} | \text{$f$ is continuous for all points except for at most 1 point} \}$. Is this set equinumerous to the set of continuous functions $C(\mathbb{R})$?

I am not quite sure where to start. Intuitively it seems that it is equinumerous, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a hint, note that you can split this up into a a pair of real numbers (the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the discontinuity) and a pair of continuous functions (the portions of $\mathbb R$ to the left and right of the discontinuity are homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ and the function is continuous on these portions).

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct. Let $S=$ the set of functions with at most one discontinuity. The cardinality of set $C$ of real continuous functions is $2^{\aleph_0} = \frak{c}$ because a continuous function is determined by its values on $\mathbb Q.$ Let $S_x=\{f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R:f\   \text{is discontinuous exactly at}\ x\}$. Then $|S_x|=\frak{c}$ and so $\bigcup_{x\in \mathbb R}S_x$ also has cardinality $\frak c$ (because the cardinality of each set in the union is $\frak c$. To finish, note simply that $S=C\cup (\bigcup_{x\in \mathbb R}S_x)$.

Comment: Isn't it $\mathfrak c^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: Yes, but don't we have $\mathfrak c^{\aleph_0}=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}= \frak c$?